# Spreading of ink

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

**Greetings,**

I was writing on my notebook and found one of the pages torn.

I cellotaped it

It was normal but after a few days I observed something weird

*[image]*

As you can see the ink was spreading over in the cellotaped region

*Why does it spill this way? Why does it need this much time(took a few days) to spill?*

Comment: Because some of the ink can absorb into the adhesive and diffuse laterally through the adhesive layer.

Answer (score 2):

To enlarge upon Jon Custer's comment:

Ordinary pen ink consists of a mix of colorant, water, and *humectant* or *co-solvent* whose job it is to lower the vapor pressure of the water in the ink and thereby prevent the ball tip or nib from drying out and crusting over when you are not writing with it.

Eventually the water will evaporate (if the relative humidity is low enough) and some of the cosolvent (usually diethylene glycol, glycerol, etc.) stays behind. What you are seeing here is the slow diffusion of the remaining cosolvent into the adhesive layer on the sticky side of the tape.